# using a varible in "urllib.request.urlopen" throws an error

Tags: python, url, urllib, urllib3

I want to get data from NCBI website using python3. When I use

```
fp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=50964")     
mybytes = fp.read()
mystr = mybytes.decode("utf8")
fp.close()
print(mystr) #### executes without any error
```

but when I pass the **id** as a variable in the url, it throws an error.

```
id_pool=[50964, 4552,7845,987,796]

for  id in id_pool:
   id=str(id) 

   url=f'"https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term={id}"'

   print(url) ## "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=50964" ### same as above

   fp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

   mybytes = fp.read()

   mystr = mybytes.decode("utf8")

   fp.close()

   print(mystr) #### shows the following error

   break


"    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: "https>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a redundant double quotes (`"`) around the url

```
f'"https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term={id}"'
```

The string became `"https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term={id}"` instead of `https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term={id}`.
Remove them and the code will work fine

Comment: but upon printing it gives "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=50964" which is the same as my previous input.
Why it is shows error then?

Comment: @shivam which one did you print? `print(f'"https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term={id}"')` gives `"https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=50964"`, `print(f'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term={id}')` gives `https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=50964` which is valid url

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=50964 is the correct URL but to get the data I need to execute urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=50964") which is enclosed by " ".

Comment: @shivam yes because urlopen function take the url as string parameter, the double quote around mark the value inside as string. You should check out [string data type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)

Answer (score 1):

There was a typo in the `url` and I've corrected it for you:

```
url = f'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term={id}'
```

Looks like you have enclosed it twice. I was able to retrieve the output:

[image]